# compatibility with modern motherboards? (ATX 12V vs EPS 12V)

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, computer-building, compatibility, intel-core-i5

I have the [Seasonic S12-600](http://www.seasonic.com.tw/pdf/datasheet/01PC/S12.pdf) in my current PC, which I'm thinking of upgrading from its ageing s939 Athlon CPU to a Core i5-based system.

My question is whether or not my PSU is compatible with modern motherboards? For example, [this P55 Gigabyte board](http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Products/Motherboard/Products_Spec.aspx?ClassValue=Motherboard&ProductID=3287&ProductName=GA-P55M-UD2) has:

1. 1 x 24-pin ATX main power connector
2. 1 x 8-pin ATX 12V power connector

The datasheet for the S12-600 suggests it has the 24-pin ATX main power connector, but it has a 4-pin ATX 12V power connector and an 8-pin EPS 12V power connector.

Will I be able to use my existing PSU to power this board, or am I going to have to replace it?

I've seen discussion (e.g. on [Tom's hardware](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/page-247828_10_0.html)) that an EPS 12V cable can be used with an ATX 12V power connector, is that right?

Many thanks for any and all help!

**UPDATE**: Reading around more, I've come to the conclusion that the connector is pin and voltage compatible with the socket on the board. I was confused by the 8-pin connector being called an EPS 12V. I took that to mean it wasn't compatible with ATX, as opposed to what it actually means (which is that its inclusion is in accordance with the [EPS standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPS12V)).

A nice summary of the PSU/motherboard compatibility can be found [here](http://www.playtool.com/pages/psucompat/compat.html).

I'm going to accept Wil's answer, since it provides the same conclusion that I've come to independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From that specification sheet, it should be compatible with any modern computer on the market.

It has many outputs and then some... Seems fine by me.

Comment: "should be compatible" and "seems fine" may still result in trashing a new mainboard with an incompatible PSU. saving on the PSU is always saving at the wrong end.

Comment: @Molly - Did you read the PDF? The PSU is a modern one with many modern outputs - It "shold be compatible" and to me, it "seems fine"... I wrote exactly what I wanted to... Do you try to stalk me and everything I write?

Comment: @wil: you have a stalker?  i'm so jealous!

Comment: @~quack don't be!... It just feels recently like pretty much every other answer I write gets criticised for seemingly no reason!